# Changes in routes.rb in rails 4.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, routes

I am trying to make an existing project by creating it in rails 4.0.0 ..

The existing `routes.rb` consists of :

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.root :controller => "homepage", :action  => 'homepage'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
end
```

My newly created project's `routes.rb`  consists of

```
Myapp::Application.routes.draw do
  get "homepage/homepage"  
end
```

I have a form in samp/app/views/homepage/homepage.html.erb
what should I change now ? , inorder to make the routes correct so that when I click submit it invokes the  homepage_controller.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include this

`post "homepage/homepage"`

will do what you want I guess, but its with your code in homepage_controller.rb to handle the form . Refer to the links in the answer from Damien MATHIEU to know more on upgrading and routing  .

Comment: It worked , but do I have to include both post and get there ?

Answer (score 1):

You're upgrading from rails 2 to rails 4.
The changes are much more deeper than just changing a DSL.

You should not have generic `:controller/:action/:id` routes anymore.
Instead, you should generate `resources`.

```
Myapp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts
end
```

This will generate the following routes:

```
posts     GET    /posts(.:format)                             posts#index
          POST   /posts(.:format)                             posts#create
new_post  GET    /posts/new(.:format)                         posts#new
edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)                    posts#edit
post      GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                         posts#show
          PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)                         posts#update
          PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                         posts#update
          DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                         posts#destroy
```

`form_for` hasn't changed since rails 2. So you can then use it like before.

See:

- [Rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).
- [Upgrading Ruby on Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html).

Comment: I changed my routes.rb based on your suggestion . Now when I enter the url `localhost:3000/homepage/homepage` . Am getting the following error 

`Routing Error
No route matches [POST] "/homepage/homepage"

Rails.root: /home/nishanth/myapp`

Comment: My "suggestion" was just an example. You have to adapt it based on the actual real case of your app, and all your controllers.